# Синхронизация разработки или использование всего доступного API back-end

Tags: планирование

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста, как лучше всего решать и какими программными средствами следующую задачу. В организации, где я работаю, есть два условных отдела, один из которых занимается разработкой front-end, а другой back-end. Тот отдел который разрабатывает back-end, так же является и разработчиком всех концепций приложения. В связи с этим разработка API(которую разрабатывает back-end) опережает фактическое использование её разработчиками front-end. В итоге возможно какое то API случайно не будет использовано полностью, и приложение не реализует какие то возможности, эти недостатки мы конечно обнаружим (а может и нет?) на этапе тестирования, но это слишком поздно. Для решения этой задачи мы пробовали заводить журнал (обычный табличный файл) куда всё разработанное back-end API записывалось, а отделом front-end помечалось как использованное, но это неудобно и несовременно. Так же мы пробовали использовать jetbrains youtrack и заводили для каждого API задачу для отдела front-end, которую они помечали как завершённую когда использовали этот API, но это тоже оказалось неудобно, в основном из за невозможности быстрой проверки, и огромной массы задач.

Comment: http://keepachangelog.com/en/0.3.0/ http://swagger.io/

Comment: К сожалению эти средства позволяют только хорошо документировать API , но совсем не контролируют обязательность использования каждого метода разработанного API

Answer (score 0):

Если это большой проект, то должна быть для него с начало написана подробная документация, для того, чтобы ориентироваться в таких ситуациях. Избежание таких моментов очень хорошо описаны в книге [Стива Макконнела "Совершенный код"](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/138437220/).
По моему мнению если back-end разработчики пишут не использующийся код, то это пустая трата времени для них.

Comment: К сожалению, на разработку подробной документации нам просто не выделили времени, да есть концепт, и есть ТЗ с подробностями уровня пользователя. Кроме этого многие возможности добавляются в процессе руководством. Back-end разработчики изначально не пишут не использующийся код, но из за отставания front-end`а какое то API может быть просто "забыли использовать".

Comment: Если в API останутся неиспользованные части то это не так уж и плохо (если конечно их не очень много) может быть даже хорошо. Может проект будет в будущем дорабатываться. Но в моей практике не подробная документация приводит к плачевным ситуациям. Особенно когда проект большой и разрабатывается командой.

Comment: Спасибо, что скинули ссылку на книжку, подскажите там действительно 2017 год издания или 2010?

Comment: 2010. Но это никак не влияет на его активность.